# How to include merged cell info when reading google sheets through `googlesheets` node library?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When reading merged cells received from [`batchGet`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) and [`get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) using the `googlesheets` API, any merged cells show up as empty except for the top left cell of the merge, how do I make the `batchGet` or `get` functions return every merged cell as the same value of the topleft cell. I can't check the previous cells and assign values as that is very unreliable as the sheet has many empty nonmerged cells.

Suppose the variable for the result from `get` or `batchGet` is called `rangeData` (for this question assume this is the result from `batchGet`).

EDIT: Here is my use case:

```
const characterRes = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId,
    ranges: characterRanges,
  });
```

using @Tanaike 's answer lead to merges with invalid indices, I don't know why, maybe because using the `sheets(merges)` field gives merges for the entire sheet and not just the ranges?

Here is the full github page, in case you want to know the very specific use case: https://github.com/ChrisMGeo/genshin-helper-data-scraper

Comment: In order to achieve your goal, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If my proposed workaround was not useful or it was not your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I fixed the question specifically for the `batchGet` function as I'm having difficulties using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

In your situation, when "Method: spreadsheets.values.get" and "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet" are used for the sheet including the merged cells, only the left side of the merged cells is retrieved. Unfortunately, it seems that this is the current specification. So, in this case, it is required to use a workaround for achieving your goal.

About `I can't check the previous cells and assign values as that is very unreliable as the sheet has many empty nonmerged cells.`, when "Method: spreadsheets.values.get" and "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet" are used, I can understand your concern. But, when the merged cell ranges can be retrieved, I thought that your goal can be achieved. In this answer, I would like to propose this as a workaround.

In this workaround, the merged cell ranges are retrieved using "Method: spreadsheets.get". Using this, the empty cells in the merged cells are embedded. The sample script is as follows. From your `node.js` tag, I used googleapis for Node.js.

#### Sample script:

```js
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: auth }); // Please use your script here.
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name including the merged cells.


// 1. Retrieve merged cell ranges using "Method: spreadsheets.get".
const res1 = await sheets.spreadsheets.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  ranges: [sheetName],
  fields: "sheets(merges)",
});
const merges = res1.data.sheets[0].merges;

// 2. Retrieve values using "Method: spreadsheets.values.get"
const res2 = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range: sheetName,
});
const values = res2.data.values;
console.log(values); // Here, you can see the retrieved values from Spreadsheet.

// 3. Embed the merged cells with the 1st value of each merged cell range.
if (merges && merges.length > 0) {
  merges.forEach(
    ({ startRowIndex, endRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endColumnIndex }) => {
      const v = values[startRowIndex][startColumnIndex];
      for (let r = startRowIndex; r < endRowIndex; r++) {
        for (let c = startColumnIndex; c < endColumnIndex; c++) {
          values[r][c] = v;
        }
      }
    }
  );
  console.log(values); // Here, you can see the result values.
}
```

- When this script is run, when the merged cells are included in the target sheet, the empty cells in the retrieved values are embedded with the 1st value of the merged cell range.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: I think I understand this solution so you use the other `sheets.spreadsheets.get` function to get the merges and then use that to merge the values in the `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get`, it seems to work in your use case, but in mine I use `batchGet` with multiple ranges which are not the entire page, so using this method causes an indexing issue, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm going to add my use case to the main question above, and hopefully that should help.

Comment: @Apoqlite Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `using @Tanaike 's answer lead to merges with invalid indices, I don't know why, maybe because using the sheets(merges) field gives merges for the entire sheet and not just the ranges?`, unfortunately, when I tested my sample script, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your current script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I've provided my scirpt in the github repo above in `index.ts` you need to get a credentials json file tho and share the sheetId in the index file to the account ur using with the sheets API project.

Comment: @Apoqlite Thank you for replying. I saw your script. But, I cannot find my proposed script. By this, I cannot still understand your current issue of `using @Tanaike 's answer lead to merges with invalid indices, I don't know why, maybe because using the sheets(merges) field gives merges for the entire sheet and not just the ranges?`. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your current issue for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Oh that's fine I don't blame you for not understanding I made it seem vague. When I use `batchGet` I used specific ranges in the sheets like for example `Sheet1!A1:I16` and there are multiple of these for every sheet, like `Sheet1!A1:I16`, `Sheet1!A21:I35`, etc. for other sheets as well. When I call the other `sheets.spreadsheets.get` I get the merges but only for each sheet and not for the ranges, so rowindex and columnindex are in relation to the whole sheet and not the ranges I gave `batchGet` and `sheets.spreadsheets.get`.

Comment: @Apoqlite Thank you for replying. From your reply, in this case, am I required to modify your showing script? And for example, when `Sheet1!A1:I16` and `Sheet1!A21:I35` are used, when those include only a part of the merged cells, what result do you want to retrieve? I cannot still understand your current issue. I apologize for my poor English skill, again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue with the Googlesheets API and/or the `batchGet` and `get`. Also it is not that you are not getting the info for the other cells, you are getting the info but they are actually empty. This is the standard behaviour of Spreadsheets. Merged cells only have value on the first cell, the rest of the cells act as if they are empty. A workaround you can do is have a script that will mirror the values of the merged cells from the first cell.

Provided another sample below using Google Apps Script `getValue` individually from the merged cell range:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

You can see here that it is empty for all the other cells aside from the first/top left cell.

---

**Please see reference link below for more information:**

- https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135735079/merged-cells-only-have-a-value-on-first-cell-rest-of-the-cells-act-as-if-they-were-empty?hl=en

Also as stated by KarlS in the reference link you can send this feature request to the developers using the in-product feedback tools. Feedback submitted there will go directly to the development team and the more people who request a feature like this the more likely it will be implemented.

**For Docs/Sheets/Slides:** You can send feedback from the Help menu > Help Sheets/Docs/Slides improve. (For some this might be "Report an issue" instead.)

Comment: Let me know if this clarifies it or you have other questions/concerns!